# Prove that for positive number, some multiple only has 0 and d as it's digits

Tags: probability, pigeonhole-principle

Let $ n$ be a positive integer, and let $1<=d<=9$. Show that some multiple
of $n$ has $0$ and $d$ as its only digits.

I don't know how to even start this question. It's under the pigeonhole section of the text book so I am guessing that we have to use that somehow. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Consider the numbers written $d$, $dd$, $ddd$, and so on. E.g., if $d=3$ these are $3$, $33$, $333$, etc. Note that if you subtract one of these numbers from a larger one, you get a number whose digits are all either $d$ or $0$.

Let $r_k$ be the remainder when you divide $$\underbrace{dd\ldots dd}_{k\text{ digits}}$$ by $n$. There are only $n$ possibilities for $r_k$: it must be in the set $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. These possibilities are your pigeonholes.

Comment: + 1 Thanks Brian!!, congrats on your $200k$. You are the big daddy here in MSA! How does it feel to touch the glory? Also, I see you are in $MSA$ all day. Do you ever sleep? Just curiosity.

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Thanks! I do sleep, but mostly during the day: I’ve always been a nightowl, and now that I’m retired, I can sleep when I’m sleepy and not worry about the clock. When I’m up, I’m usually on-line, and if I’m on-line, I check MSE periodically, even if I’m also doing something else.